# android codes for inserting math symbols

Tags: java, android

I'm stucked with trying to find out how to insert math symbols to my app  through TextView. i've tried using WebView with jqmath but couldn't make it work.

if TextView would not work, then steps using WebView or ListView or any other Views would be considered.

Comment: What do u want to enter ? and what math expression ?

Comment: which *math symbols* exactly are you interested in?

Comment: Listview? What? There's this library for a math view to display LaTex symbols. If you want to insert with edit text, use a different keyboard

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of stuff? https://github.com/kexanie/MathView and https://github.com/Nishant-Pathak/MathView

Comment: i mean like integration signs, square root, subscripts, superscripts, submission sign etc.

Comment: If the Unicode solution that Vlad Matvienko suggested didn't work, try to put the symbols as HTML code then put the HTML code string into TextView. This is [explained here](https://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use almost any unicode character in Android. Below is how to use it.
Every character has it's own code. For example square root is `U+221A`, which in Android looks like `\u221A`.
This way to include it to your string, use it as follows: `String expression = "\u221A4 = 2"` (square root of 4 is 2).

[Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm) you can find a list of all characters with their codes.

Comment: thanks a lot Vlad, it works. but, i can't seem to get these symbols to work though,i.e.,  differentiation (dy/dx, not partial differential), subscripts and superscripts of 0 (zero) and of alphabets (like x subscript n, x superscript n), also, i couldn't get +/- symbol to work either. But most of the stuffs i wanted works.

Comment: @l.b. sub and sup can be achieved using simple HTML tags like `<sup>`, `<sub>`